# How To Add Different Images In Li

Tags: html, css, list

i am trying to make horizontal socail media links in un-ordered list i tried by putting simply `img` tag in li its worked but misalignment images please check my code and help me out

```css
body{
  background:#080;
}
.social-sites {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.social-sites ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.social-sites ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.social-sites ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-sites">
  <ul>
    <li class="fb">
      <a href="facebook.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.closetoyou.co/v/vspfiles/assets/images/fbook.png" />Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li class="twit">
      <a href="twitter.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9Z46uKc.png" />Twitter</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ld">
      <a href="linkedin.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.vds-horeca.nl/media/12768/linkedin_icon_small.png" />LinkedIn</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use `display:inline-block` AND `float:left`. Pick **one**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from li tag and set same height for img tag and add some margin to right side.

```css
body{background:green}
.social-sites{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.social-sites ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.social-sites ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle 
}

.social-sites ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align:middle;
   display: inline-block;
} 
.social-sites ul li a img{
  width:40px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-sites">
  <ul>
    <li class="fb">
      <a href="facebook.com" target="_blank">
        <img src ="http://www.closetoyou.co/v/vspfiles/assets/images/fbook.png"/>Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li class="twit">
      <a href="twitter.com" target="_blank">
        <img src ="http://i.imgur.com/9Z46uKc.png"/>Twitter</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ld">
      <a href="linkedin.com" target="_blank">
        <img src ="http://www.vds-horeca.nl/media/12768/linkedin_icon_small.png"/>LinkedIn</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all the images with the same height. I also add some margin to have space.

```
.social-sites ul li img{
  max-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```css
.social-sites{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.social-sites ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.social-sites ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.social-sites ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
} 

.social-sites ul li img{
  max-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:green;">
<div class="social-sites">
            <ul>
                <li class="fb"><a href="facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src ="http://www.closetoyou.co/v/vspfiles/assets/images/fbook.png"/>Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="twit"><a href="twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src ="http://i.imgur.com/9Z46uKc.png"/>Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="ld"><a href="linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src ="http://www.vds-horeca.nl/media/12768/linkedin_icon_small.png"/>LinkedIn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

add image width and height

```
<ul>
  <li class="fb">
   <a href="facebook.com" target="_blank">
    <img src ="http://www.closetoyou.co/v/vspfiles/assets/images/fbook.png" width="30"/>Facebook</a>
    </li>
  <li class="twit">
   <a href="twitter.com" target="_blank">
    <img src ="http://i.imgur.com/9Z46uKc.png" width="30"/>Twitter</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ld">
   <a href="linkedin.com" target="_blank">
    <img src ="http://www.vds-horeca.nl/media/12768/linkedin_icon_small.png" width="30"/>LinkedIn</a>
  </li>
</ul>

 .social-sites ul li a img{
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
 }
 .social-sites ul li {
      display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just adjust the `img` width.

You have to only add this code:

`.social-sites ul li a img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}`

```css
body { background-color:grey;}
.social-sites{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.social-sites ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.social-sites ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.social-sites ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
} 

.video-image {
    left: 417px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 74px;
}
.fret_vids {
    text-align: center;
}
.navigation-container {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.social-sites ul li a img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-sites">
            <ul>
                <li class="fb"><a href="facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src ="http://www.closetoyou.co/v/vspfiles/assets/images/fbook.png"/>Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="twit"><a href="twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src ="http://i.imgur.com/9Z46uKc.png"/>Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="ld"><a href="linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src ="http://www.vds-horeca.nl/media/12768/linkedin_icon_small.png"/>LinkedIn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```